# RxJs Help in Angular / SharePoint Search HTTP Call

Tags: angular, typescript, sharepoint, rxjs

I have done a great deal of work trying to refactor this method (and maybe this is as simple as it can get).  I am calling a SharePoint Search Query API, which is returned in a strange JSON way (nested and nested - example below code).  This code simplifies it to optimize for consumption in an Angular ngFor.  However, I am hoping to get some insight on how I could simplify this, as I am still struggling with RxJs.  TIA!

```
getSearchQuery(term) {
return this.http.get(this.variables.spUrl + this.queryAPI + '%27' + term + this.queryOptions + '%27', this.options)
    .map(res => res.json().d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results)
    .map(data => data.map(item => item.Cells.results))
    .map((data, i) => {
        data.map((object, i) => {
            this.newProp = {};
            object
                .map(prop => {
                    let key = prop.Key;
                    let value = prop.Value;
                    this.newProp[key] = value;
                });
            object = this.newProp;
            this.newData.push(object);
        });
        console.log(this.newData);
        return this.newData;
    })
    .share()
```

}

Code that console.logs the image attached below:

```
    getSearchQuery(term) {
        return this.http.get(this.variables.spUrl + this.queryAPI + '%27' + term + this.queryOptions + '%27', this.options)
            .map(res => res.json().d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results)
            .map(data => data.map(item => item.Cells.results))
            .do(data => console.log(data))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you have `this.newProp`? It always set one time per first object map. Do you need to store `this.newData` in the class?

Comment: I was only using them to get what I needed.  I don't need either for anything else other than this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
getSearchQuery(term: string) {
  const url = `${this.variables.spUrl}${this.queryAPI}%27${term}${this.queryOptions}%27`;
  return this.http.get(url, this.options)
    .map(res => res.json().d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results)
    .map(rowResults => rowResults.map(item => item.Cells.results))
    .map(this.remapResults)
    .do(data => console.log(data)) // Do whatever you want with new data.
    .share();
}

remapResults(results:  any[]) {
  return results.map(object => {
    const newProp = {};
    for (const prop of object) {
      const {Key, Value} = prop;
      newProp[Key] = Value;
    }
    return newProp;
  });
}
```

Comment: Actually when I try this I get error "core.es5.js:1084 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'Rank' of undefined"

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot to change `this.newProp` to `newProp`, edited my answer.